# Hibernate ElementCollection/JoinTable IntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I'm having 3 JPA Entities like this as well as the corresponding JPA-Repositories.

```
@Entity
public class ChairEntity {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinTable(name = "chair_image")
  private Set<ImageEntity> images = new HashSet<>();
  ...
}

@Entity
public class TableEntity {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinTable(name = "table_image")
  private Set<ImageEntity> images = new HashSet<>();
  ...
}


@Entity
public class ImageEntity{
  ...
  private String description;
  @Lob
  private byte[] data;
  ...
}
```

Using a REST-API these Objects are created and updated. This works usually fine, e.g. i may add multiple imageEntities at once like this (all codes blocks are inside their own transaction)

```
chairEntity.getImages().add(new ImageEntity(..));
chairEntity.getImages().add(new ImageEntity(..));
chairRepository.save(chairEntity);
```

...or update multiple ImageEntities of the same chairEntity at once.

```
chairEntity.getImages().stream().forEach(imageEntity -> {
  imageEntity.setDescription("some other description");
}
chairRepository.save(chairEntity);
```

In both cases all Changes are successfully cascaded and saved.

If, however, I am updating an existing ImageEntity as well as adding another entity, it fails:

```
chairEntity.getImages().stream().forEach(imageEntity -> {
  imageEntity.setDescription("some other description");
}
chairEntity.getImages().add(new ImageEntity(...));
chairRepository.save(chairEntity); // crashes
```

The exception is as followed (an equivalent error is thrown using h2db):

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "chair_image_pkey"
```

When inspecting the DB-Log, it seems like Hibernate is trying to:

1. inserting the new image (successfully)
2. updating the existing image (successfully)
3. inserting an entry into the Join-Table/Collection-Table (chair_image) referencing the chair and the existing image. This then throws this JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, as this combination of Foreign keys already exists (the old image already existed before).

Why is this happening and how do i solve it? Saving and Flushing the Changes individually inside the same transaction doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @CollectionTable should not be used in this context. It's for basic types like Strings, Enums and Embeddable, but not for Entities: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. Still, hibernate treats it the same way as @JoinTable in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround, in case anyone else comes across this problem: Reverse the order of operations:

```
chairEntity.getImages().add(new ImageEntity(...));
chairRepository.saveAndFlush(chairEntity);
chairEntity.getImages().stream().forEach(imageEntity -> {
  imageEntity.setDescription("some other description");
}
chairRepository.save(chairEntity); // crashes
```

The order in which hibernate executes the SQL-Statements stays the same, but due to the flush between, the faulty insert into the Join-Table no longer happens.